# Can't persist data on self referencing column

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I have a strange issues when i want to persist entity which holds reference to itself.

DB:

Table `PROJECT` has Column `PARENT_ID` which holds references to itself.

Model:

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Model_Name")
 * @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
 **/
```

`protected $_parentId;`

Code:

`$project->setParentId(int);`

After setting `PARENT_ID` i persist entity, and all data except `PARENT_ID` are stored inside DB.

**EDIT**

Id field/column

```
/**
 * @Id
 * @Column(type="integer", name="ID")
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $_id;

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getParentId()
{
    return $this->_parentId;
}

/**
 * @param  int $parentProjectId
 * @return Application_Model_Data_Project $this
 */
public function setParentId($parentId)
{
    $this->_parentId = $parentId;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Can you post more code? That part looks just fine.

Comment: @mbinette rest of code in entity is just getters/setters, persist is in controller so nothing special to add. I see that you posted self-referencing as Many-To-One/One-To-Many and i have One-to-One, all other association mapping work fine, only this particular one doesn't :(

Comment: The reason why I asked for more code was so I could see how you defined the ID of Model_Name and make sure it fits. Because what you posted looks fine. And please add the used setter too... Maybe it's just something like writing `$_parentId = $id;` instead of `$this->_parentId = $id;` ??? (Hey, everybody makes that stupid mistake once in a while... ;-) Especially when switching between languages!)

Comment: Setters/Getter work good, because when i remove mapping annotation from `$_parentId` data is stored in DB.

Comment: Can you try to remove the JoinColumn line, just to see how doctrine2 will react? (it should still pick up the entity id, the only difference would be the column name in the table - we'll work from there)

Comment: After trying to persist entity i have error from doctrine: "Found entity of type on association Model_Name#parent, but expecting Model_Name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post more code? That part looks just fine.

Here's a SSCCE of a working self-referencing entity. Maybe that'll help.

```
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="messages")
 **/
class Model_Message
{
    /** 
     * @Id @Column(name="message_id",type="integer") @GeneratedValue 
     **/
    protected $id;

    /**
     *@ManyToOne(targetEntity="Model_Message")
     *@JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="message_id")
     **/
    protected $parentMessage;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Model_Message", mappedBy="parentMessage")
     **/
    protected $replies = array();

    [...]
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to save a relationship to another object with doctrine, you must save the object, not the id. Which means you have to set the Model_Name object, and not the id (integer) in your variable tagged as a Model_Name (targetEntity). (Doctrine will use the int automatically in the DB).

See my example above with the ManyToOne.

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Model_Name")
 * @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
 **/
protected $_parent;


[...]

/**
 * @param  Model_Name $parentProject
 * @return Application_Model_Data_Project $this
 */
public function setParent($parent)
{
    $this->_parent = $parent;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: thanks for help... you forgot about `cascade={"persist", "remove"}`

Comment: It's not needed, you can just make sure you persist the entities separately. :) But use cascade={'all'} if you want it to cascade everything (persist, remove, merge, detach)!

Comment: ah, so in my case is needed as i persist only one entity :)
thanks again !